# How to use () initializers for vector in class?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This code gives an error

```
class Board {
  vector<vector<int>> sudoku(9, vector<int>(9));
// Error; Expected a parameter declarator
};
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> sudoku; Board() : sudoku( 9, vector<int>(9)) {}`? or `vector<vector<int>> sudoku{9, vector<int>(9)};`

Comment: The first option works! The second option however, still gives an error. Thanks!

Comment: What compiler are you using? I tried 4 … https://godbolt.org/z/5dBnZm

Answer (score 6):

You can't use parentheses to directly initialize a member when you do in class initialization.  You have to either brace (`{}`) or equal (`= ...;`) initialize the member.  That means you need to refactor it to have the form of

```
vector<vector<int>> sudoku = vector<vector<int>>(9, vector<int>(9));
// or
vector<vector<int>> sudoku{9, vector<int>(9)};
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
class Board {
  vector<vector<int>> sudoku = vector<vector<int>>(9, vector<int>(9));
};
```

Second way:

```
class Board {
public:
    Board() : sudoku(9, vector<int>(9)) {}
private:
    vector<vector<int>> sudoku;
};
```

Comment: *Second (and recommended) way:* Why is it the recommended way?  Many prefer in class initialization so that you don't need to repeat intializers in all the contructors.

Comment: @NathanOliver it keeps the code more organize, and separate the code into more logical sections.

Comment: I think using "recommended" is just an opinion; answers should try to stay in fact. If it was always going to be the same initialization, and I have ten different constructors, I sure wouldn't put it on the initializer list of 10 different constructors.

Comment: The [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-in-class-initializer) also suggest to prefer default member initializers to constructor initializer lists. So the latter being "recommended" seems at least opinionated.

Comment: @walnut Well I can't argue with a book, fixed. Thanks!